# Create separate classes for a custom Antlr4 target

Tags: antlr4, stringtemplate-4

I am creating a custom target for Antlr4 based on the Java.stg template. In the Parser part of the template the class for the Parser is generated along with some helper classes (extending for example ParserRuleContext). All these classes are included in one single file.

For the new target language however I cannot include more than one class definition per file. Is there a feature in Antlr4 to generate separate files for every generate class?

Comment: Not really familiar with the generating part of ANTLR (and string-template), but the C++ target contains multiple .stg files: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master/tool/resources/org/antlr/v4/tool/templates/codegen/Cpp Perhaps that might help you? Just curious, what target language are you working on?

Comment: Thank you Bart for the link. I had not noticed that the CPP target had multiple templates, certainly worth investigating! Currently I am working on Matlab as a target language for Antlr4.

Comment: Matlab, nice! I've not encountered too many questions about new ANTLR target languages here on SO. Might be worth asking your question at the source, if this one remains unanswered: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Answer (score 0):

The stg files are just sources (templates) for the generation process. What matters is the files that are produced by ANTLR4 and they always contain only one class, unless you manually add another one.

Comment: Ok, but my problem is that those generated classes are added to one single file for the target language in the template.

Comment: Tbh. I don't understand why this is the case for you. In any target language where I created parser/lexer files, each class was stored in its own file (one for the lexer, one for the parser, for the visitors and listeners, the interp file etc.).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, indeed one class is generated for the listener/visitor/parser and lexer. But inside the parser there are also definitions of classes, e.g. classes which derive from the ParserRule Context. Thus I have a Parser file in which other classes are defined.

Comment: Ah this one, but they are local classes. They do not count as multiple class definitions. Actually, you cannot even declare them differently or they are not local classes anymore.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the classes won't be local anymore, but the target language does not allow more than one class definition per file.

Comment: Local classes count as separate class definitions? That's odd. Which is your target language? But anyway, you cannot change that. It's coded into ANTLR4 to create local classes for the individual rule contexts.

Comment: Target language is Matlab